# Adding a character on a string from a HTMLInput using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this `htmlInput` in an `ASP:Repeater` that I want to be formatted in time format (e.g: `13:39`) on its `keypress`. So far I have this code in repeater databound:

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpt.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim txt As HtmlInputText = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtKmRun"), HtmlInputText)
            If txt IsNot Nothing Then
                txt.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return kmRun('" & txt.Value & "');")
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

..and this is in the JavaScript:

```
<script>
        function kmRun(myValue) {
            String x = myValue;
            x = x.substring(0, 2) + ":" + x.substring(2, x.length());
            alert(x); //alert to test display but is not working
            //HOW TO PASS x VALUE TO BACK TO THE TEXTBOX?
        }
</script>
```

Tested the `onkeypress` attribute with a simple [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)alert message and it worked but when modified with value passing, there's no return value. So I guess, the error starts there.

Additional question is when the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)part works, how to return the "converted" string value back to the `htmlInput`? Is there any other solution for this problem that will not use a `PostBack`?

Thanks.

===================

This is the working code:

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpt.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim txt As HtmlInputText = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtKmRun"), HtmlInputText)
            If txt IsNot Nothing Then
                txt.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return kmRun(this);")
            End If
        End If
End Sub

<script>
        function kmRun(x) {
            if (x.value.length > 2) {
                x.value = x.value.substring(0, 2) + ":" + x.value.substring(2, x.value.length); 
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare another variable, you can use the `myValue` parameter.

I'd recommend to use `onchange="kmRun(this)"` instead `onkeypress="kmRun(this)"`, because you got to change the content, to finally be formatted by the code.

By using `this`, you can get all attributes of the textBox control.

You might try something like this, in your javascript code:

```js
function kmRun(control) {
  control.value = control.value.substring(0, 2) + ":" + control.value.substring(2, control.value.length);
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" type="text" onchange="kmRun(this)" value="" />
```

Comment: You're welcome @eirishainjel. If you need more help, you can ask when you wish. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your logic.

- You're sending `txt.Value` inside your `ItemDataBound`, but it will be a fixed value when rendered in your `HTML`, since it will not get updated when the user types. You must change that:

  ```
  txt.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return kmRun(this.value);")
  ```

  The keyword `this` above refers to your `input`, and whenever the user types, it will get updated.
- Javascript is not a typed language, there is no `String x =` declaration. You must use:

  ```
  var x = myValue;
  ```
- You shouldn't use `.substring(0, 2)` directly without validating if the field has more than two characters, because if it doesn't, the browser will throw an error.
- You're using `.length` as it was a method, but it's a property. Don't use the parenthesis `()`.

---

Finally, to pass the value back to your `TextBox`, you can do:

```
this.value = x;
```

Comment: just put the this.value = x; at the end of the javascript function? i'm sorry, i'm not really familiar with javascript.

Comment: @eirishainjel yeah, that's it.

Comment: Thank you for the input, Sir! :D